# Remove parts from AppleScript result

Tags: applescript

I want to remove a part of an AppleScript result. The part of my whole code is following

```
list disks
```

I get the result: `{"Macintosh HD", "MobileBackups", "home", "net", "USB-Stick"}`
How can I remove the part `"Macintosh HD", "MobileBackups", "home", "net"`, so that only volumes that are not the whole time available are shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
set mydisks to list disks
set newdisks to {} as list
repeat with currentdisk in mydisks
    if ((currentdisk as string) is not equal to "net") and ((currentdisk as string) is not equal to "home") and ((currentdisk as string) is not equal to "Macintosh HD") and ((currentdisk as string) is not equal to "MobileBackups") then
        set newdisks to newdisks & currentdisk
    end if
end repeat
```

You will have your desired list on `newdisks`.

Comment: This isn't the correct method though. It won't work if any of those names change, like say with an OS update.

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Finder" to set disklist to every disk whose ejectable is true or local volume is false and name is not "home" and name is not "net"
set namelist to {}
repeat with diskitem in disklist
    set end of namelist to name of diskitem
end repeat
return namelist
```

Comment: Those AppleScript one-liners are quite something.

Comment: I get an error notification: `number -1728 from 1 to «class furl»`

Comment: I'm getting a very long result. Should I post it?

Comment: With the new script I get as result "MobileBackups" - Thanks :)

Comment: @user121028: Ok, I admit I was wrong several times. I think this one may actually work. I define "not the whole time available" to means either plugged into a USB port or connected through the internet.